# How do i correctly implement a conditional debounceTime() operator with the use of the iif() operator?

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6, iif

I have a `BehaviourSubject` that is subscribed to via the getSaveBehaviorSubject() in the constructor of a `Service`.This behavioursubject can receive multiple types of data from other components/services of which some types need to be stored in the backend while others do not. When it receives a value that does need to be stored it sends it to the backend via a `put/post` request. As a request rate limiter I'm using the `debounce(300)` operator so that the actual request to the server is made after 300 ms of inactivity have passed. This will prevent the server from throwing a `429 Too many requests` error. The debounce operator should only be applied when a value type is pushed that needs to be stored. I've tried creating such a condition with the `iif()` operator. My code looks like this:

```
this.myService.getSaveBehaviorSubject()
.pipe(
  tap(pair => {
    if(this.dataStoreServiceJustInitialized){
      this.dataStoreServiceJustInitialized = false; 
      return;
    }

    if (pair.length > 1){
        this.updateDataTypeValue(pair);
        localStorage.setItem(pair[0], JSON.stringify(pair[1]));
        if(pair[0] === DataType.MEASURE_SYSTEM_PREFERENCE)
            this.adjustSearchRadiusToChangedMeasureSystem();
    }
  }),
  mergeMap(pair =>
    iif(() => !!(this.loggedInSubject.value && this.dataTypeExclusionList.includes(pair[0])), 
    of(pair).pipe(debounceTime(2000)), of(pair)
    )))
.subscribe(pair => {If (this.loggedInSubject.value) // make request to server...}
```

My solution is based on this tutorial: https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/conditional/iif and the code of interest starts at `mergeMap`.

If the user is logged in and the datatype should be saved to the database (is not contained in the `dataTypeExclusionList`) then `iif()` should return an observable with a pipe containing a `debounceTime` operator. Else it should just return a new observable with the original value.

When the `iif` condition is true debounceTime does not seem to be working. No matter if i'm loggedin or not or if the datatype should be saved or not it will always send the request immediately. Clearly i'm doing something wrong.

Could anyone tell me what the correct way is to use the iif operator in combination with the debounceTime operator? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues here:

1. `debounceTime` will emit its current value immediately when its source completes - without waiting for the timeout. The `of` factory will produce one notification and then complete right after. Therefore, there is no debouncing happening. You could fix this by replacing `debounceTime` with `delay`, as it will wait to emit even if the source has already completed.
2. You are using `mergeMap`, which will not unsubscribe from the previous Observable when it gets a new notification. Therefore you could have a case where `getSaveBehaviorSubject` emits 100 times within the timeout and you would send 100 server requests. You can fix this by replacing `mergeMap` with `switchMap`.

Applying both should fix your issue.

But, I would recommend a different approach: Make use of the `debounce` operator. Instead of a timeout value, you pass in a function that returns an Observable. When this Observable emits, the current value will be forwarded.

Like this:

```
this.myService.getSaveBehaviorSubject().pipe(
  tap(...),
  debounce(pair => {
    if(... debounce condition ...) {
      return timer(2000);
    } else {
      return timer(0);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: charm ! :) thxxx